# What is wrong with this function? I can't get the button to appear and the function to run

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
     function changeBgImage(){
    document.body.getElementbyId.style.backgroundImage = "url('colombia.jpg')";          "getElementbyId:'links'"}
    </script>
    </head>

<body>

<img src="worldcup.jpg" id="worldcup" height="200" width="600">
<img src="logo.jpg" id="logo1" height="200" width="200">
<img src="logo.jpg" id="logo2" height="200" width="200">

<p id="teams"> <big> <big> Teams that are in the World Cup </big></big>
 <br> <big> Group A: </big>
 <br> Brazil, Mexico, Croatia, Cameroon <br>
 <big> Group B: </big>
 <br> Netherlands, Chile, Spain, Australia <br>
 <big> Group C: </big>
 <br> Colombia, Ivory Coast, Japan, Greece <Br>
 <big> Group D: </big>
 <br> Costa Rica, Uruguay, Italy, England <br>
 <big> Group E: </big> <br>
 France, Ecuador, Switzerland, Honduras <Br>
 <big> Group F: </big> <br>
 Argentina, Nigeria, Iran, Bosnia
 <br>
 <big> Group G: </big> <br>
 Germany, United States, Ghana, Portugal <br>
 <big> Group H: </big> <br>
 Belgium, Algeria, Russia, Korea Republic 
 </p>

<p id="favorites"> 
<big> <big> <big> <big> My Favorites </big> </big> </big> <br>
  In this section of my webpage I would like to talk about my Favorite teams, 
  obviously I am rooting 100% for Colombia because it is my country, as well as Costa Rica. 
  Another obvious team I always root for is the US, because well...I'm also American. This World Cup has been 
  so great, I am extremely proud of all of the Latin American teams that have qualified for the next round and I 
  hope that a Latin American team makes it to the final. I am very excited because I will be in Miami for the final and I 
  am sure it will be very exciting. 
 </p>
    <img src="colombia.jpg" id="colombia" height="400px" width="400px">

<p id="soccerlove"> <big> <big> <big> Why I LOVE soccer! </big></big>
<br>
There are many many reasons why I love soccer. First of all, I was raised watching soccer games
and cheering on my family's favorite teams. It becomes a tradition,and when you are away from your family, you can watch a soccer game and feel at home. 
Soccer is such a beautiful sport, on the two videos on either side of this section you will find 2 reasons why I think soccer is so beautiful. On the left, a compilation 
of amazing goals, and on the right, the way that Colombian celebrate their goals! </p>

    <p id="goal1">
    <iframe width="350" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RGEm9T4Smts"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>
    <p id="goal2">

    <iframe width="350" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FEJzRdU1viE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>

<p id="links">
<h1> Who do you think will win? </h1>
<form>
<input type="button" name="links" id="links"
    value="Who will be the winner?!"
    onclick="changeBgImage">
    </p>
<form>
```

So I need the function "changeBgImage" to run...how can I get it to work 
I would like for it to be a button at the bottom of my page. I have tried it various ways and I am still not able to get it to work, is there anyone that can help me out with it please?

Comment: In most browsers these days, pressing 'F12' will open the developer console, and show you the errors.

Comment: What are you trying to change the background image of? A div? `body`?

Comment: @user3791013 were you trying to change the page background or a div?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.getElementbyId.style.backgroundImage = "url('colombia.jpg')";
```

`getElementById` is a function, and it requires a parameter.

`getElementById("idofyourelementhere");`

I have no idea what you're doing with `"getElementbyId:'links'"` by the way. It looks like you're trying to use object syntax without setting to a variable? Or using proper notation..

Comment: And let's not forget to ask what the `"getElementbyId:'links'"` at the end of that function is doing.

Comment: @j08691 that one I'm pretending is a horrible, horrible typo.

Comment: function changeBgImage(){
 document.body.getElementbyId('links').style.backgroundImage = "url('colombia.jpg')" Is that still wrong?

Comment: @user3791013 Check your spelling on `getElementById`, in your original post and this comment, you have the B in By lowercase, where it needs to be uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be there :

```
"getElementbyId:'links'"}
```

your `<form>` is not correctly closed ;

getElementbyId should take an id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change the page background

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('colombia.jpg')";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jzmsb/

If you're trying to change the background of something else it needs an id

```
<div id="changeme"></div>
```

and you target it with

```
document.getElementById("changeme");
```

giving

```
document.getElementById("changeme").style.backgroundImage = "url('colombia.jpg')";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jzmsb/1/

Comment: It doesn't look like he's trying to change the page background. He has the getElementById right in there, so obviously he's trying to change the background of a specific element already. He's just not calling getElementById right.

Comment: It does: his code read `document.body...`, but he may not be, which is why I gave both scenarios